# Is this crack actually on the heat exchanger? I thought the coils were the heat exchanger. Is this crack a cause for concern? Need a new system?

Tags: furnace, heat, air-exchanger

[image]

I discovered this crack while checking for any signs of trouble in my furnace. I thought the coils in the photo were the heat exchange system and I don't know if that strip with the crack in it means just that strip can be replaced or if the whole system needs to be replaced.

Comment: Do you have a working CO detector in the vicinity?

Comment: Normally the "coils" refers to pipes that carry refrigerant from/to an outside compressor for air conditioning and/or heat pump. Technically that is a "heat exchanger". But the heat exchanger of safety concern refers to the area where hot air from combustion exchanges heat with indoor home air. The concern being CO (CO2 and other things as well, but CO is the biggest concern). Any evaluation of your crack would require seeing more of the furnace to figure out where it is relative to the gas burner. And as noted in another comment, a CO detector is a very, very good idea.